# Azure Email Communication Service with Node Js

Tags: azure, html-email

I am using Azure Communication Email Service. I am using it in Nodejs for Sending Mails to outlook users and the message type is HTML.

The issue I am getting is with the images which I have in the html message, but In outlook app those images are not visible.

If you know anything about how the message should be and how to provide images please let me know.

The **Image URL** I have provided is https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1496181133206-80ce9b88a853?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2071&q=80

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send an email with images in body using ACS email service, it is not supported as of now.

I would suggest you raise a [feedback request](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/81ff6d2b-0c25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0858) from here. ACS engineering team actively monitor this feedback and work on them accordingly.

At this moment you can send the images as an attachment using ACS email service.you refer to the [sample code here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/communication-email-readme?view=azure-node-latest#send-email-with-attachments) on how to send an email with attachments.